# What's the use case of a file.contents to be a Stream in vinyl file

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, filesystems, gulp

Reading the doc of [vinyl](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl#isstream), I can't see any use case of a file.contents to be a Stream in vinyl file. If you can provide some examples, tutorials or Github repos it would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if the file were so big it wouldn't fit in RAM? It is useful for the same reason any stream is useful.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Sorry, but the idea is too abstract, I still don't know when I would use it.